# Parsing arabic data in xml

Tags: java, string, split, arabic

i've a java application that parses xml files each file contains arabic data, the problem that these data comes from the backend with a lot of tabs and spaces and there is no way to change them on backend, and when i'm trying to split such data i found that the order of the words not correct although before removing the tabs the order was fine, the problem occurs alot when there is combination between left-to-right and right-to-left in my case arabic and english

Example

```
String s="مثال          لنفس     الحالة";
s.split("/t");
```

example for combination

```
String combinationString="بمبلغ     2867.51     ريال سعودي      رقم العملية     LD1131900120";
s.split("/t");
```

Comment: If s contains letters as you read them (right to left), then of course the String[] that split returns is left-to-right from 0 up. Is that your problem?

Comment: the problem occurs alot when there is combination between left-to-right and right-to-left in my case arabic and english so that when doing split or replace the tabs the english words change its order which makes aproblem

Answer (score 0):

To retain the original order of letters (and words) in any string while removing redundant white space, do the following:

```
String s="مثال          لنفس     الحالة";
s = s.replaceAll( "\\s+", " " );
```

Of course, this also replaces a single TAB by a presumably more convenient space.

Comment: the problem occurs alot when there is combination between left-to-right and right-to-left in my case arabic and english so that when doing split or replace the tabs the english words change its order which makes aproblem

Comment: the string may contains more than one tabs combined with whitespaces